# Excel - VLOOKUP formula with fallback possible?

Tags: excel

Using Microsoft Excel, I'm trying to fill in a column with data using `VLOOKUP`.
 I would like to build a formula that is able to do a **fallback** to another datasource, depending on a given outcome.

I'm first looking at one source (the preferred source) and if the data is not there I'm doing a `VLOOKUP` in another data source. In the adjacent column, I want to automatically indicate which data source the number is coming from based on what part of the formula was used to pick up the number. Is this possible?

A simplified example would be:

```
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(information from data source 1), VLOOKUP(information from data source 2)
```

If it picked up a number in column A from data source 1, the adjacent cell in column be would say data source 1, if it picked up the number from data source 2 then the adjacent cell would say data source 2.

Comment: Just check whether the lookup value exists in the primary data source in the adjacent column. `=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(lookupvalue,source 1 lookup column, 0))),"Source 1", "Source 2")`

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(information from data source 1))),"Source 1","Source 2")
```